# Prevent backtracking of function

Tags: prolog, backtracking

Is it possible to specify to not backtrack a certain function? For example with the following code the `somestatisticalfunction` could be assumed to always be correct, and does not need to be backtracked. So when backtracking I would want Prolog to only backtrack the `dosomethingelse(Output)` and `length(Ls, Size)`.

```
f(Ls) :-
    length(Ls, Size),
    somestatisticsalfunction(Size, Output), % Don't backtrack this
    dosomethingelse(Output).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
somestatisticsalfunction(Size, Output),
```

use:

```
once(somestatisticsalfunction(Size, Output)),
```

to succeed at most once. See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=once/1

I would also look at improving `somestatisticsalfunction` to prevent unwanted choicepoints.